# Trouble writing a query for two tables using these tables (below)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

**MySQL**

I am trying to fetch value's from a table Province that has a foreign key of country table.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM province 
  JOIN country 
    ON country.Country_Id = province.Province_Id
```

[country table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7ffy.png)

[province table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4od3V.png)

**What I am trying to do:** I want all the entries to shown in one single table on my PHP web page.

Error is : [warning page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGIOI.png)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You think `country.Country_Id = province.Province_Id` will give you the right result????

Answer (score 0):

first you have to specify the current column in join statement you mentioned that country_id is the foreign key in province table then you have to have:

```
SELECT province.*, country.name  
  FROM province 
  INNER JOIN country 
    ON country.Country_Id = province.country_Id
```

and since in the result set both country and province has country_id, using one of them would be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple `LEFT JOIN` like below :

```
SELECT * FROM province 
LEFT JOIN country ON province.country_Id = country.country_Id
```